# Transfer Core Data Over Segue - Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to save a few NSStrings to Core Data, and then access them from a UITableView in another view controller. Here is the code I am using to save the strings to Core Data:

```
- (IBAction)GoBackButton:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:Title forKey:@"title"];
    [newDevice setValue:Step1 forKey:@"step1"];
    [newDevice setValue:Step2 forKey:@"step2"];
    [newDevice setValue:Step3 forKey:@"step3"];
    [newDevice setValue:img forKey:@"imagename"];


    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"goBack" sender: self];
    reloadType = @"YES";

    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And here is the method I'm using to try and transfer the data back across through the segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goBack"]){

        [[segue destinationViewController]setManagedObjectContext:self.device];
    }

}
```

However, the line:

```
[[segue destinationViewController]setManagedObjectContext:self.device];
```

brings the error "No known instance method for selector 'setManagedObjectContext:'. I can post more of my Core Data Model creation code if needed to help find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your other viewcontroller should also have access to core data methods (like also be able to read and write to your database). I would strongly recommend adding your strings to either an array or a dictionary and pass this instead.

Anyways, the reason it is not working is because you have to import your other view controller header, and then cast it.

Something like:

```
MyOtherVC *temp = [segue destinationViewController];
[temp theMethodIWannaUse:theData];
```

Furthermore, you HAVE to implement it on your other view controller, like if you want to set core data then you have to make your core data object public in the header (or at least the method that you want to use) of your destination view controller.

Edit:

The VC to present must have this in the header:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
```

and then just pass it like this on the prepare for segue:

```
MyOtherVC *temp = [segue destinationViewController];
[temp theMethodIWannaUse:theData];
temp.context = *theContext*;
```

Comment: How do I make the core data object public in the header of the destination view controller? I am trying to set core data as you are saying above.

Comment: add @property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; in the header of that other view controller.

Comment: I have done as you suggested. It is giving me the error "no visible @interface for 'Second View Controller' declares the selector 'setManagedObjectContext:'" on the same line shown in my question. Thoughts?

Comment: change that line to temp.managedObjectContext = *the context you want to pass here*; By the way, the problem you are facing doesnt have anything to do with Core Data. its more about using methods/properties from another class.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help so far (I'm somewhat new to this). I still can't solve these error messages. I have this line in the .h of both view controllers: @property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *device;. It has an error saying the property 'managedObjectContext' not found on view controller. How do I fix this?

Comment: Ok, I think you are complicating the things, core data functions should be kept in one place (having them in many can get very messy). My suggestion is, use delegates. Make the controller with core data perform the tasks for the new vc. The new vc will set the presenting vc as its delegate, then every time you need the data just use its delegate. http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002 . But really if the data is static just pass an NSArray with the strings you need.

Comment: Ok. Gonna use NSArray to pass my data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
DetailComplaints *detailComplaints = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]
                         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailComplaints"];
detailComplaints.tempWebData=[self.detailWebServce objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//detailComplaints.tempName=[self.detailWebServce valueForKey:@"username"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailComplaints animated:YES];
```

}

and recieving to other viewcontroller like this...
`

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
  //  NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
```

`
and then ..

```
_txt_name.text= [self.tempWebData valueForKey:@"username"];
    _txt_address.text=[self.tempWebData valueForKey:@"address"];
    _txt_phone.text=[self.tempWebData valueForKey:@"phonenumber"];
```